# Insert methods of string into 2d array Angular 4

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm trying to make a web page, in this page I need to dysplay in column 6 images of people with their names and description. But I'm stuck trying to display their name and description. Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
 export class TeamComponent implements OnInit {
 public team: any[][];
 title = ' Team ';
 name: string;
 description: string;

constructor() {
this.team = [
  [this.firstTeamMember(), this.secondTeamMember()],
  [this.thirdTeamMember(), this.fourthTeamMember()],
  [this.fifthTeamMember(), this.sixthTeamMember()]
 ];
}

firstTeamMember(): {
this.name = 'A name';
this.description = 'text';
}

secondTeamMember(): {
this.name = 'Another name';
this.description = 'text';
}

thirdTeamMember(): {
this.name = 'Another name';
this.description = 'text';
}

fourthTeamMember(): {
this.name = 'Another name';
this.description = '...';
}

fifthTeamMember(): {
this.name = 'Another name.';
this.description = 'text';
}

sixthTeamMember(): {
this.name = 'Another name';
this.description = 'text';
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div class="team" *ngFor="let i of team">
<span *ngFor="let j of i">
{{j}}
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use objects instead of functions

```
firstTeamMember = {
    name: 'Another name',
    description:'text'
}
```

then your array will look like this

```
constructor() {
    this.team = [
        [this.firstTeamMember, this.secondTeamMember],
        [this.thirdTeamMember, this.fourthTeamMember],
        [this.fifthTeamMember, this.sixthTeamMember]
    ];
}
```

and your component will look like this

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div class="team" *ngFor="let i of team">
    <span *ngFor="let j of i">
        {{j.name}}
        {{j.description}}
    </span>
</div>
```

if you want to use functions,
the array should not execute the function, `[this.firstTeamMember(), this.secondTeamMember()]`, store the function in the array and execute it in the html

```
export class TeamComponent implements OnInit {
    public team: any[];
    title = ' Team ';

    constructor() {
        this.team = [
            [this.firstTeamMember, this.secondTeamMember],
            [this.thirdTeamMember, this.fourthTeamMember],
            [this.fifthTeamMember, this.sixthTeamMember]
        ];
    }
}
```

the functions should have isolated variables instead of global ones, so change from `this.name` to `const name = 'name'`;

```
firstTeamMember(): {
    const name = 'Another name';
    const description = 'text';
}

secondTeamMember(): {
    const name = 'Another name';
    const description = 'text';
}

thirdTeamMember(): {
    const name = 'Another name';
    const description = 'text';
}

fourthTeamMember(): {
    const name = 'Another name';
    const description = 'text';
}

fifthTeamMember(): {
    const name = 'Another name.';
    const description = 'text';
}

sixthTeamMember(): {
    const name = 'Another name';
    const description = 'text';
}
```

Component.html

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div class="team" *ngFor="let i of team">
    <span *ngFor="let j of i">
        {{j().name}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you told me to do.

Comment: instead of executing the function and storing it in the array, store the function in the array and execute it in the html.
so instead of the array containing 
`[this.firstTeamMember(), this.secondTeamMember()]`
it should contain
`[this.firstTeamMember, this.secondTeamMember]`
 without the brackets ().

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this way and it works but it only displays me the sixthmember six times

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
 <div class="team" *ngFor="let i of team; let i = index">
  <span *ngFor="let j of i">
   {{j}}
  {{ name }}
  </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: you get the same name because you name variable is on the class, and it picks up the name assigned by the sixthteamMember